# SharePoint default view get selected item programmatically

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list-view

In SharePoint lists and libraries we have a default list item view. If I select 20 items from default list view as I am selecting check box from default view, how can I get those selected item ID:s programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by writing client side object model code:

```
function GetSelectedItems() {
    var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var selectedItems = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(context);
    var listId = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedList();
    var itemIds = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < selectedItems.length; i++) {
        itemIds += selectedItems[i].id + ",";
    }
}
```